# Google Sheets sort question

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-filter

I used to know this a few years ago and for the life of me can't figure it out and can't find an answer in Google help.

I know how to sort columns, but only by the default A-Z format, how can I sort some columns by that and secondary ones by words that aren't alphabetical, like military rank?
I know a couple of ugly workarounds, but I'd like the real deal.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I need it sorted by alphabetically by column D first, then column E (which I know how to do), then by C, which is the rank of the soldier and this (sorting by text) is the only one I can't figure out

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lMCs8p7S_7PmqWv3PwF7disrleXCQ9XWKPyfrJzPpl4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I would be able to give the ranks a number i.e. a numerical rank, if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways how to do it. Either use **Create a filter** or **Create new filter view** under **Data** after you select all columns:

[image]

[image]

---

The 3rd option would be to use a formula to sort the data based on a **custom sequence** which needs to be priorly defined

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({Sheet21!A2:N, 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet21!C2:C, {Z2:Z, ROW(Z2:Z)}, 2, 0))}, 
 "order by Col4,Col5,Col15", 0), 9^232, 14))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to do it with assigning a number to their rank and using that to sort, I didn't know if there is a way to assign that rank/sequence

Comment: @Mike answer updated. also your sheet updated with sheet **Sheet21 sorted** that contains the formula and it sorts stuff as you wish based on custom order in **Z** column

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very useful for me!

Comment: I can't upvote because I'm new

Comment: @Mike no worries, next time ;)